# Two-sample z-test proportions/Experimental Design

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Can we use a two sample z-test for proportions when conducting a randomized experiment (comparing the proportions in a treatment group vs a control group that were affected by a treatment)?  When a student asked me this, I initially thought no because the condition of comparing two independent samples cannot not satisfied for this test---maybe I am wrong.  For instance, when we are using means in experimental design, don't we use paired tests (which does not have the condition of comparing two independent populations), not a two sample t-test for means.  Is this the correct way of thinking about this?